# Are there any API to get real money value equivalent of a transaction?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, gas-price

I know that etherscan shows the total cost of a transaction both in eth and in US dollars.

Is there any api of any kind to be able to get instant value of eth when I send a transaction?

Comment: Just use the CoinMarketCap API to grab the ETH/USD price data, then calculate the value of your transaction? https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#

Answer (score 2):

Your best choice atm is to use [coinmarketcap api](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/). It gathers data from many different markets and provides an average price market. Alternatively, you can make use of markets APIs, like [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/features/api), [Coinbase](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/), etc .. 
Hope it helps.